# How to reconnect socket.io client on activity after auto-reconnect times out?

Tags: javascript, socket.io

It is common for laptops to go to sleep. This causes the socket.io client to disconnect. When the user returns to the web app, the socket.io client doesn't try to reconnect (probably reconnection limit reached?). How do I tell the socket to reconnect if the user does some action?

For example, I'd like the `emit` function to check if the connection is active, and if not then try to reconnect.

Note: I only need the client-side JS code and I'm not using node.js.

Answer (score 7):

In version 0.9 you could try to set the connect options object to some aggressive settings:

```
  var main = io.connect('/', {
    'reconnection delay': 100, // defaults to 500
    'reconnection limit': 100, // defaults to Infinity
    'max reconnection attempts': Infinity // defaults to 10
  });
```

Note that `max reconnection attemps` does not mean that the io client will stop to reconnect to the server after 10 failed attempts. If it was able to reconnect to the server 10 times and loses the connection for the 11th time, it will stop to reconnect.

See [Socket.IO Configuration](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO)

Answer (score 4):

Socket instances have an inner 'socket' property, which in turn has connect() method that you can call.  It's normally called automatically when you instantiate the object (controlled by the 'auto connect' option).  The inner socket also have a boolean "connected" property which you can check if you're not sure what the state is.  Like so:

```
sio = io.connect();
//... time passes ...
if (! sio.socket.connected) {
  sio.connect();
}
```

The connect() method checks to make sure that the socket isn't in the middle of trying to connect, though for some reason it doesn't check to see if it's already connected.  Not sure what happens if you connect() an already-connected socket...

The source code for the client library is fairly clear and well commented, which is good since [the README on github](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client#readme) doesn't provide a whole lot of help.  It's handy to use an un-minified version of the library while you're doing development so you can dig into the source.

Comment: Thanks Dirk. Where would I put this to tell socket.io to reconnect if not connected whenever the client tries to send something to the server?

Comment: Depends a lot on how your code is structured.  You could put a wrapper around emit() that checks connection state.  You could have an on("disconnect") function that pops up a dialog asking if the user wants to reconnect.  You'll also have to experiment to see what actually happens when you close the lid on a laptop.  Not sure how the socket.io code will perceive that...

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use the `connect.failed` event:

```
socket.on('connect_failed', function () {
   /* Insert code to reestablish connection. */
});
```

Comment: I tried that already. The problem is the connect_failed is not fired after the laptop wakes up or after a lost wireless is reconnected. That's why I'm thinking of tying reconnect to the user activity, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: +1 because this method is called when laptop wakes up. But I still need a way to try reconnected after the auto-reconnect times out and socket.io gives up, such as when there is no network connectivity.

Answer (score -2):

You could have a setInterval running which checks connected status like

```
s.connect()

if (! s.socket.connected) {
   s.connect();
```